# Fragment OnInflate never called

Tags: android-fragments, attributes, android-inflate

I'm trying to use the custom attributes but the onInflate method is never called.
Here is my code:

```kotlin
class NavigationBarFragment : Fragment() {
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_bar, container, false)

        // get arguments
        val title = requireArguments().getString(ARG_TITLE, "")
        //[...]

        binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(view)!!
        val viewModelFactory = NavigationBarViewModelFactory(title)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(NavigationBarViewModel::class.java)
        binding.viewModel = viewModel

        return view;
    }

    override fun onInflate(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onInflate(context, attrs, savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, having the same issue. Could you share your solution (if any) ?